# Android WebView can't display jquery-fullpage page properly

Tags: android, jquery, webview, fullpage.js

The page is implemented by jquery-fullpage plugin, like this:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

In android app, `WebView` doesn't display it properly. It overlaps all the sub pages in one page without scrollbar.

Any idea?

Comment: Also, make sure to use the latest verison of fullpage.js

Answer (score 0):

Version of your browser maybe affect. Check [issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/14) on Github.

Remember enable javascript in your WebView:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
         /* Enabling javascript */
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```